# What do I returns in 'IsLike' types when either of the params is invalid?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What do i return when the input of the type `IsNegative` is `Invalid`?

Should i return `never` ? `unknown` ? `boolean` ? anything else ?
What is the best practice to use in similar cases ?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMoF4oG8DOw7AQBcUA5AG6KqkA0UKBcJeATkgHYDmAvgLABQoSFACS7SsjSZc+QiVIcJ1PvwFDoAaQ5TYVNAB9R4vQLXhoInADkInAknLQAPAEEoEAB6F2KHFC0+AHwYAlBhUG6e3r66klCh4QD8EVAA2qQM+KQAuu5eED5+AAYAJFgcAGYQLFAAwgAWcCzcZXDsINxFCeFJdY01UQUxpAC0pFDJwCwArtAkFYg4EN09UCTsEI41APTbUBtbUI1gkOw4K-IA7o3AUMAA9lAsEMDTLGcTpEA)

```
type Valid = {state: 'valid', data: string}
type Invalid = {state: 'invalid'}

type Kind = Valid | Invalid

type IsNegative <A extends Kind> =
    A extends Valid 
    ? A ['data'] extends `${infer Char}${any}`
        ? Char extends '-' ? true : false
        : never // never happens
    : 'what to returns ?'
```

Answer (score -1):

One'd expect a boolean - extended - type to return true or false. So, I'd suggest returning `false` to keep your boolean logic in both last cases;

```js
type IsNegative <A extends Kind> =
    A extends Valid 
    ? A ['data'] extends `${infer Char}${any}`
        ? Char extends '-' ? true : false
        : false
    : false
```

If you need to reason about why it's not negative, maybe a type is not the appropriate language feature to use.  A function would do.

```js
function assertNegative<K extends Kind>(kind: K): boolean{
     // some pre-validations & possibly throw errors
     if( yourValidationFails){
           throw new Error("Type Invalid passed instead of Valid")
       }
  return true;
}
```

Or if you don't want to throw errors, gracefully return a Status structure:

```js
type Status = {
     result: boolean,
     reason?: string
  }

function isNegative<K extends Kind>(kind: K): Status{
   // some pre-validations
     if( yourValidationFails){
         return { result: false, 
                  reason: "Type Invalid passed instead of Valid"
             }
         }
      }
  return { result: true };
}
```

Comment: In first case it never happens since if the string is empty it would still extends `${infer Char}...` , so never should not be changed here! Besides that your answer for me is misleading, as if I returns a valid answer it can leads to error further - sorry but I won't validate it

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't find it useful. I hope you give it a second careful read anytime soon. Besides, can you expand on which of my proposals  would  lead to error when returning a valid answer?

Comment: if you request an answer while expecting the input to be valid, and get's the same answer if the input is invalid, it can be confusing, as if you use the result as input in another type you won't be able to differentiate between a valid input and an invalid one. It's a question on a best practice as you can come up with this issue pretty often when trying to build types thet can be helpful to build other types

Comment: Not sure one of my proposals follow that description. But you've the right to disagree. I'm keeping my main comment for future reference. Hope you find the answer that suits you best.

Comment: When input is Invalid it can't be negative but cannot be either positive as it holds no data - using your type gives the information that the input is non negative, i.e. positive - even if the input is invalid - which is incorrect

Comment: As I saw it `isNegative` type should only care about saying if yes or no something is negative. That's the case when an input is `InValid` or string is empty. Only the reason of non negativity changes.  The conclusion - on positivity or error - is up to your code logic.  That what I was expanding on in my **last two code examples**.  But from your way of thinking about this, I see that returning  `never` would do; if ever a type the appropriate  feature to use.